# User Profile Layout With UITableView Advice

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, user-profile

I am creating a user profile that will display three types of data: posts/pictures/differentPosts.
Similar to instagram profile. I need help with the layout. I was thinking of using a viewController with two tableViews(for the posts) and a collectionView for the pictures. They would all be on top of each other and three buttons would determine which view to is going to display and be hidden. Is this bad programming practice and is there another way I should go about it

Comment: I don't think it is bad practice.  I use overlapping views on occasion.  I mean sure, using tab bar is cool when you only have 3-4 views of info.  But what if you have more?  Then your idea makes sense.

Comment: How did you do this in the end Peter?

Comment: I ended up using a `UICollectionView` for everything. I used a header file for all the person profile information, and a `uisegcontrol`. For each selected state of the `SegControl`, i change the `dataArray` and `cellreuseIdentifier` to either pictures or posts array/cell reuse identifier. @ChrisEdwards

Comment: Cool ok thanks. I ended up using multiple controllers inside one parent screen, and just swapping the parents view to be the view of the selected controller